# Adding Namespace To Route Service Provider NOT WORKING

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-9

I'm working with Laravel 9 and I want to use Laravel Old Style of routing.

So inside `RouteServiceProvider.php`, I added this:

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

Then for the `web` routes:

```
Route::middleware('web')
     ->namespace($this->namespace)
     ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```

And after that, inside `web.php`:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('panel', [PanelController::class, 'index']);
});
```

So I didn't specify `use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PanelController;` in this file since the namespace is defined.

But don't know why when I goto 'admin/panel' url, I get **Target class [PanelController] does not exist.** error meaning that the namespace is not working correctly!

So how can I declare the namespace properly, so I won't need to use every single controller for routes?

Answer (score 0):

write down with `Admin\PanelController` and check

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('panel', [Admin\PanelController::class, 'index']);
});
```

Comment: Still not working

Comment: what was the error now?

Comment: Target class [Admin\PanelController] does not exist.